# What is the proper ES6 way for appending an indexed item to an Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, immutability

If I have an Object like so :

```
var state = { 10: [Object], 12: [Object, Object], 13: [Object, Object, Object] }
```

I would like to add a new object to the end of one of the subarrays without mutating the original Object. Instead, returning a new object via ES6 :

I am admittedly daft of understanding of both immutable Objects and ES6. And this is my first attempt at this, but this ( for obvious reasons ) does not work.

```
  return  {
    ...state,
    [12]:
      state[12], Object
  }
```

Would anyone know the proper syntax to produce this? :

```
var state = { 10: [Object], 12: [Object, Object, Object], 13: [Object, Object, Object] }
                                                 ^---- One extra object at the end of `12`
```

Comment: It is object spread syntax, but it is in stage 2 standard proposal.
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {12: state[12].concat([newObject])});
```

or with ES6 array spread syntax

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {12: [...state[12], newObject]});
```

or with the experimental object spread syntax

```
return {...state, 12: [...state[12], newObject]};
```